# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a way on a website, for a user to 'bid' on an item, similar to ebay. I'm getting the error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

This is for the line:

```
user_bid = int(request.POST.get("bid"))
```

I think it thinks 'bid' is None or NoneType. But I'm not sure why. Is there a way to convert this into a float or int? When I do:

```
int(float('bid') or int(float(request.POST.get('bid') it also doesn't work.
```

I need to convert it to int or float because I cannot use the > with a string, I just get another error. I'd appreciate any insight you have!

views.py

```
def new_bid(request, listingid):
    current_bid = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
    current_bid = current_bid.starting_bid
    if request.method == "POST":
    
        user_bid = int(request.POST.get("bid"))
        if user_bid > current_bid:
            listing_items = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
            listing_items.starting_bid = user_bid
            listing_items.save()
            try:
                if Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid):
                    bidrow = Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid)
                    bidrow.delete()
                bidtable = Bid()
                bidtable.user = request.user.username
                bidtable.title = listing_items.title
                bidtable.listingid = listingid
                bidtable.bid = user_bid
                bidtable.save()

            except:
                bidtable = Bid()
                bidtable.user = request.user.username
                bidtable.title = listing_items.title
                bidtable.listingid = listingid
                bidtable.bid = user_bid
                bidtable.save()

            Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid)
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "i": "id"
            })
        else:
            response = redirect('listingpage', id=listingid)
            response.set_cookie('error', 'Bid should be greater than current price', max_age=3)
            return response
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Try printing the dict `request.POST` and see what happens.

Comment: `user_bid = int(request.POST.get("bid") or <default_value>)`

Comment: If you need a default value for the post: `int(request.POST.get("bid", default_value))` is the proper way of doing that

Comment: @MZ  thank you, when I tried these though I got an error saying default_value needs to have a value. So right below this: if request.method == "POST" I did default_value = None and then user_bid = int(request.POST.get("bid", default_value)). This time the page allows the user to type a bid into the box on the page. But then I get the error again: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'    I'm sorry I'm new to this, but any more help is really appreciated. I'm not quite sure where the default_value should go and how to make it work with syntax